# Override core permissions used for visualizing a page

Tags: 7, users

Is there is a way (without using any external module) to override the core drupal 7 pages access permissions , for example and by default you will not be able to access **/admin/structure/taxonomy/tags** page without having (**Administer vocabularies and terms)** permission , but I want the users to be able to access it if they have for example **(Edit terms in Tags)** permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it by writing a custom module that implements `hook_menu_alter()`.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['path/to/change']['access arguments'] = array('permission name');
}
```